# slow for i loop in python

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop

I am having trouble optimizing a for i loop that uses time sequence data that bases the next result on the previous one.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.Series(range(1,1000000))
df=df.to_frame(name="CusUnits")
df['UpperBoundary'] = 10
df['LowerBoundary'] = -10
from progress.bar import Bar
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
length=len(df)
df.loc[0, 'Hedged'] = df.loc[0, 'CusUnits']

for i in tqdm(range(1, length)):
    if (df.loc[i, 'UpperBoundary'] > (df.loc[i-1, 'Hedged'] - df.loc[i, 'CusUnits']) > df.loc[i, 'LowerBoundary']):  df.loc[i, 'Hedged'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Hedged']     
    else :df.loc[i, 'Hedged'] =df.loc[i-1, 'CusUnits']
```

Comment: what is the pass is doing in the for loop?

Comment: Could share a small, reproducible example ?

Comment: you can replace the if/elif lines with `if (dataframe.loc[i, 'UpperUnits'] < (dataframe.loc[i-1, 'Hedged'] - dataframe.loc[i, 'CusUnits']) < dataframe.loc[i, 'LowerUnits']:  dataframe.loc[i, 'Hedged'] = dataframe.loc[i, 'CusUnits']`  and better assign the `len(dataframe)` value in a variable instead of calling it in every loop

Comment: Remove duplication. If you've copied and pasted anything, replace it with a variable.

Comment: Edit the question. Make it great. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @azro pls see now i edited so its an exmple you can re produce it

Comment: @ghostOps yes correct but even with the changes the iterations per second when I go to million of records the iterations drop to 100 something per sec

Comment: @PeterWood yes thanks I did but still performance is very poor

Comment: sometimes you can get faster code when you don't display text on screen because it need a lot of time - so maybe it will run faster without `tqdm`

Comment: maybe you could use `shift()` to move `Hedged` `CusUnits` to previous row and then you could run with `apply` instead of `for`-loop and `i-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in tqdm(range(1, length)):
    if (df.at[i, 'UpperBoundary'] > (df.at[i-1, 'Hedged'] - df.at[i, 'CusUnits']) > df.at[i, 'LowerBoundary']):  df.at[i, 'Hedged'] = df.at[i-1, 'Hedged']     
    else :df.at[i, 'Hedged'] =df.at[i-1, 'CusUnits']

the replacement of loc with at solved many thanks for you comments
```